# A better solution to host static files besides Amazon S3

Tags: ajax, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I made a mobile application in static html, which is equal to my site wordpress site

The first version was completely static, all texts were in the mobile HTML application.

Today, I updated my application to pull data from the wordpress with AJAX.

The problem is that now, with so many requests being made, the S3 bucket is not being enough.

Despite having decreased from 6kb to 83kb, but it is still more slow because of AJAX..

is it possible put static applications in some other service from Amazon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the static content, you should probably be looking at [AWS CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) instead of S3. As per the page itself:

`Amazon CloudFront is a content delivery web service. It integrates with other Amazon Web Services products to give developers and businesses an easy way to distribute content to end users with low latency, high data transfer speeds, and no minimum usage commitments.`

Other thing you can leverage is the AJAX caching. That will make your webpage load much faster from the next time. You may also want to using `nginx` on your server for caching (this will reduce your server load)